# Struggling to sign Company Hub XAP file

Tags: windows-phone-8, code-signing

We use a system known as AirWatch to manage our BYOD.  To roll out Windows Phone 8 properly we needed to obtain a Symantec code signing certificate.  With that we can deploy an AET and use it to sign their MDM Agent file.  This last part is proving tricky.  No matter what I try I get the following error:

```
SignTool Error: This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognised.
SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: "temp location of AirWatch XAP file"

XapSignTool Error: signtool.exe failed with exit code 1.
```

I have tried using a different path to the SignTool.exe file as there was a suggestion that using the the x64 instead of x86 variant could be the cause.

I have checked the certificate chain is installed correctly.

All in all I am a bit lost as to what is wrong.  My main issue is I have no concept of which file it is moaning about being in the wrong format!  Does anyone have any guidance that may have been through similar?

Using Windows 8.1 with the Windows Phone 8 SDK installed.

Command being run is:

```
XapSign sign /v /signtool "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86" /f "C:\symantecCert.pfx" /p [password] "C:\AWAgent_Release_CompanyHun_AnyCPU_323.xap"
```

Comment: Have you had any success with this? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem yesterday. To me it made no sense but installing silverlight runtime resolved the issue! I would've thought if it was required it would have been included in the SDK package.